# How to send data to server with javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm a good back dev, but have a huge problem at front. So, i have a form that download photo to send it to server.

```
 <form name="Forma"  id="photoForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" name="btn_file" id="loadFileXml" value="Выбрать фото" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
                <input type="file" id="file" style="display:none" name="photo" required accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif " />

                <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary " hidden id="Test1">Проверить</button>
            </form>
```

And here is a function that should send data to server, for getting JSON response (i'm not sure with it,

```
var fileuploadinit = function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
        var pathwithfilename = $('#file').val();
        var filename = pathwithfilename.substring(12);
        console.log(this.value);
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').removeAttr("hidden");
           $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
    
         reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
    

    });
};


$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    fileuploadinit();
});


 $('#file').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            console.log("Оппа, выбрали файл!");
        console.log(this.value);
        // $('#Test1').attr("disabled", "false")
        $("#Test1").removeAttr("hidden");
        $('#Test3123').attr("src", this.value);
        $("#info").removeAttr("hidden");
    } else { // Если после выбранного тыкнули еще раз, но дальше cancel
        console.log("Файл не выбран");
    }
})
var button = document.getElementById("Test1")
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;



function handleButtonClick() {
    alert("Вы нажали на кнопку");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/api/upload";
    xhr.open("Post", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "url/");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 & xhr.status == 200){
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
    console.log(json.name);
    }
    };
    var data = new FormData(photoForm)
    
    xhr.send(data);
    }
```

So, i spent on it for like 2 days, and absolutely don't know how to get photo from form to server. i tried literally everything, i think. It works, then i use action at html form method.

Comment: So where is `handleButtonClick` called? Where is `photoForm` declared?

Comment: Should not you add onSubmit=handleButtonClick() to you form tag?

Comment: Also you should remove space from `button type="submit "` otherwise it is wrong type

Comment: code updated. photoForm - it's just a form. I check handleonclikc - it works, there is a problem with uploadimg